# Displaying table records using CListview in Yii

Tags: php, yii, clistview

I have a simple model named Service with attributes(ServiceId, name, description, Image) ,
and  i want to display all the records in a view using CListview but only the name and description attribute, not all of them.

I am able to display the model but i cant find a solution to hide the id and image attributes.

Can anybody give a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code :

Controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Service();

    $this->render('index',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and my View:

```
<h1>Services</h1>

<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change your model's view. It is propably located in `protected/views/service/_view.php`, where service is your's controller name.

You can delete lines related to displaying ids and other attributes or change formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your protected/views/service/_view.php 
 Update below code

```
<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('name')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->name), array('view', 'id'=>$data->name)); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('description')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->description), array('view', 'id'=>$data->description)); ?>
    <br />


   </div>
```